# update Query for “Shifting row value down for one column” ( postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 10000 rows like this table

```
 id         name         gradeId
------------------------------------------              
1327        test0        1
1330        test1        1
1331        test2        1
```

i want to update the name column (Shifting values down for name column) I want the Result Like this

```
 id         name         gradeId
------------------------------------------              
1327        test1        1
1330        test2        1
1331        test3        1
```

Comment: you mean like "replace 'test' with '' then parse the result to a number, add 1 to it and prepend 'test' again" ?

Comment: @CaiusJard  for example replace test1 with test2 and test2 with test3 .... i want replace the value testxxx by the value of the next row ... 1,2, 3 tthis numbers just for example

Comment: "Next row" implies some ordering. By order of what?

Comment: @CaiusJard order by id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
update t
    set name = tt.next_name
    from (select t.*, lead(name) over (order by id) as next_name
          from t
         ) tt
    where tt.id = t.id;
```

Of course, the last `name` will be set to `NULL`.

To put in a fixed value for the last row, just use a default value for `lead()`:

```
update t
    set name = tt.next_name
    from (select t.*,
                 lead(name, 1, <default value>) over (order by id) as next_name
          from t
         ) tt
    where tt.id = t.id;
```

Comment: yes Gordon this is true thanks  but  i will insert a fix value not null in the last row..  how to do this

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the number from the text, cast it to number and add 1, then cast it back to string and concat it to the original text.

```
UPDATE grades 
SET name = CONCAT('test', CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 5) AS INTEGER) + 1 AS TEXT));
```

Comment: the numbers 1, 2, 3 in name column values, this is just an example,
i want to update name value in first row to name value in second row based on id